# Bibliography pushes header upwards

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, pagestyle

I'm relatively new to LaTeX and I now encounter an issue where I'm not sure what exactly causes it. I have my thesis written in the `book` class and have added a relatively simple page header using `titlesec` consisting of some text (chapter number/title) and a single line.

Each chapter has its own bibliography section (using BibLaTeX) at the end, and any bibliography page which is completely filled seems to push the line in the header upwards, causing it to overlap with the header text. The last page (not completely filled with references) is fine, which leads me to believe the bibliography page style is somehow forcing the text margins to expand in order to completely fill the page where possible.

I have included a MWE below. I always compile using XeLaTeX, if that's relevant.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \setstretch{1.05}
    \usepackage[paperwidth=17cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry} 
    \geometry{inner=30mm,outer=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[pagestyles,clearempty]{titlesec}
  \newpagestyle{main}[\small]{
    \renewcommand{\makeheadrule}{\rule[-0.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{0.6pt}}
    \sethead[Chapter~\thechapter]% even-left
            []% even-center
            []% even-right
            {}% odd-left
            {}% odd-center
            {\chaptertitle}% odd-right
    \setfoot[\large\thepage]% even-left
            []% even-center
            []% even-right
            {}% odd-left
            {}% odd-center
            {\large\thepage}% odd-right
  }
  \pagestyle{main}


\usepackage[style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
    \AtEndPreamble{\defbibheading{bibliography}{\section{\refname}}}
    
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter{Chapter title}

\lipsum[1-10]\cite{aksin,almendro,angenendt,aristotle:anima,aristotle:physics,aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric,augustine,averroes/bland,averroes/hannes,averroes/hercz,baez/article,baez/online,bertram,brandt,britannica,chiu,cicero,cms,coleridge,companion,cotton,cotton,ctan,doody,gaonkar:in,gaonkar,geer,gerhardt,gillies,glashow,gonzalez}


\clearpage
\begingroup
\setstretch{0}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\scriptsize}
\printbibliography[title={References}]
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Actual (erroneous) output obtained:

[image: Screenshot of actual (erroneous) output obtained.]

Actual (valid) output, from the following page:

[image: Screenshot of next page, with valid output.]

Desired output format:

[image: Page 1 of 2, of desired output. A Lorem Ipsum text block.]

[image: Page 2 of 2, of desired output. Continued Lorem Ipsum text block.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This question could be improved by adding a screenshot of the problematic output you obtain, along with a clearer description of your desired output.

Comment: Thank you, I have added some screenshots of the respective MWE in my original post. Image 1 and 2 show text pages with the preferred output, whereas image 3 is the page containing the bibliography with the header issue. Image 4 then shows the second bibliography page which looks fine again.

Comment: That helps a bit, but it's still unclear to me exactly what you want or what is wrong with the header, in photo 3 (now re-ordered to appear first, in my edit). Are you simply referring to the position of the left header title, being incorrectly aligned? Is there anything else?

Comment: I'm talking about the positioning of the line in the page heading, which seems to have shifted upwards and is overlaid on the 'Chapter 1' text. It should be aligned below as on the other pages.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by replacing the `baselineskip` spacing between the text and the line in the header to a rigid length (in my case `-4pt`). A rather simple fix in the end. Thank you for willing to help.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I'd suggest writing up your solution, in detail (ideally with images and code), as an answer. You can then accept your own answer to your question. This will help others in a similar situation (and also lead to your accruing more "reputation" on this site).

Comment: I'd also note, that while it's great that you found a working solution, it would be better to not manually edit spacing like that. I'm not exactly sure what's going on here, and don't have time to look into it, but perhaps if you post your answer, someone else will suggest an improvement!